# undefined method `next_element' for #<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x....>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I want to get the next element text by previous I'm doing like this

```
property_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(my_url))

address = property_doc.xpath('//section[@class="container"]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "Address")]').next_element.text
```

but `error` occurred  `undefined method 'next_element' for #<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x....>`

I want to next element text which is showing at `html` :

```
<section class="container">
<dl>
<dt>Address</dt>
<dd class="">550 Seagaze Dr<br>Oceanside CA 92054 </dd>
</dl>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
property_doc.xpath('//section[@class="container"]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "Address")]')
```

This instruction returns an array. Just pick the first element:

```
address = property_doc.xpath('//section[@class="container"]/dl/dt[contains(text(), "Address")]')[0].next_element.text
```